# Ensemble Techniques - Bagging | Subset size

Tags: ensemble-modeling, ensemble-learning

I do have a question on ensemble techniques Baggging/Boosting.
- What would be the subset size for Bagging?

Answer (score 1):

like said in a previous answer, the exact subsample parameter value depends on your data.

But a usual starting parameter that gets you good results in general, and doesn't hurt the data distribution much is **0.9**.

Taking out 10% of your data at each iteration or newly constructed tree, makes your model generalize a little better. You can try out different variations of the 0.9 and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Bagging describes predicting based on the average result ob multiple models you created training on random subsets of data.

For example in scikit you can configure your Bagging models with `max_samples` to tell him how many subsets to use. (see sklearn doc: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html)

If you're asking how high it "should" be, the answer is depending on your total volume of training data.

Comment: Thanks Philips, Do we have a rule of thumb for the same?

Comment: You mean a rule of thumb how many samples to use?

Comment: Yes, the rule of thumb for how many samples to use. 
Also, it would be great  to know, what happens if we do not use the parameter **max_samples**

Comment: the default for max_samples is 1 (check  the documentation I attached as example). This means that the subset will have a size of "1" which basically means you do no bagging. As rule of thumb you can use a sample size the same size as the size of your training data.